# Im trying to add elements to an array in a nested query in mongoose using Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Im getting an empty array at the end of Async.waterfall not sure why but this how my code looks like:

```
exports.GetJobs = function(req,res){
     var Jobs =[];  ///// Jobs is a global variable

    async.waterfall([
        function(next){
            // get my alert
            UserAlertDB.find({User:req.user.id},function(err,AlertResult){
                next(null,AlertResult);
            })
        },
        function(AlertResult, next) {

            // You might get an error if you do not have created an alert so AlertResult[0].Words will not exist
            if(AlertResult) // if Alert Result not equal to null then query by alert
            {
                JobDB.find({title: new RegExp(AlertResult[0].Words, 'i')}, function (err, JobResults) {

                    if (err) console.log(err);
                    // If the job matches the requirements for alert then push it to the list
                    JobResults.forEach(function(job){
                        JobOffer.find({JobID : job._id, JobOfferOwnerID: req.user.id}, function(err,Offers){
                            if(err) console.log("Error Inside Querying Jobs Result for Alert " + err);

                            if(Offers.length==0){
                                console.log("Jobs are : " +  JSON.stringify(Jobs)) // when I print the Jobs array here it shows that a job is getting pushed into the array
                                Jobs.push(job);
                            }
                        })

                    })
                    next(err,Jobs) // But Jobs here is empty
                })
            }
            else{
                next("There is an error",null)
            }
        }
    ], function(err,Jobs){
        console.log(JSON.stringify(Jobs)); ////// Getting Empty Jobs here
        if(err) console.log("Error Inside Get Jobs Match Alert Data in Server : " + err);
        res.json(Jobs);  ////// Jobs here is empty
    });
  }
```

so if you notice that when I try to send the Jobs array at the end with the res.json(Jobs) has empty Jobs although I have pushed those jobs in the Jobs array.

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your code is that the JobResults.forEach is synchronous and you are calling asynchronous  JobOffer.find inside the forEach loop. Therefore, your program doesn't wait for asynchronous operations to finish and calling the next(err, Jobs) immediately. Instead of forEach use async.each and call next(err, Jobs) only when async.each is finished. I would also advise to make sure you are checking the err value in every callback, for example here you are passing null even though there might be error:

```
 // get my alert
 UserAlertDB.find({User:req.user.id},function(err, AlertResult) {
     next(err, AlertResult);
 })
```

Hope it helps, let me know if you need any other help with your code.